# Single observer is not calling onError()

Tags: java, android, observable, rx-java2

I've written the following code in my MainActivity of an Android app. When I run the following code, it doesn't throw any exception and onError() also doesn't get called. However I see `onSuccess: testing starts` **twice** but I don't see `onSuccess: testing ends`. Why isn't onError() being called and/or why isn't the app crashing?

```
Single.timer(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Long initiationTimeStamp) {
                        String s = null;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: testing starts");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess:test  "+ s.isEmpty());
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: testing ends");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `s.isEmpty()` on a `NULL` String, thats why it ends at first print. That said `onSuccess()` does not throw anything, so it just stops execution when `NullPointerException` is thrown (it is silently handled inside RxJava for you). As soon as you subscribe to observable, you get initial value in `onSuccess()`, then if it changes or you resubscribe you get another value in `onSuccess()`, thats why it gets called **twice**. And because `onError()` is for errors occurring along the operation chain, you do not get an error in `onSuccess()` when exception is thrown.

---

This behaviour is intentional. According to Rx Contract, an observer should not receive both `onSuccess()` and `onError()`. You need to handle the exception in `onSuccess()` by yourself.

For example:

```
Single.timer(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Long initiationTimeStamp) {
                    try {
                        String s = null;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: testing starts");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess:test  "+ s.isEmpty());
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: testing ends");
                    }
                    catch (Throwable ex) {
                        // tell the upstream we can't accept any more data (OPTIONAL)
                        dispose();
                        // pass error to error handler
                        onError(ex);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

---

Good luck :)

Comment: I don't want the onSuccess to swallow exception since the exception that was occuring in my app was uknown unlike the example in the question. In that case if the exception doesn't propagate to onError or crash the app, the app's behavior might become unexpected which in not desired.

Comment: That's intentional. According to Rx Contract, A observer should not receive both onSuccess and onError. You need to handle the exception in onSuccess by yourself.

Comment: I understand that but how would you do that for unknown exceptions that you don't know about before hand?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: I can respect the Rx Contract.  What I do not understand is the thinking behind SILENTLY swallowing exceptions.  How does that help?  And the fact that this is not a well-publicized behavior is troubling.  Why isn't printStackTrace() called on the caught exception, so that it is at least revealed?

Answer (score 0):

`onError` is for errors that happen along the operator chain. What you do in `onSuccess` is already at the end of it, and will not be reported in `onError`.

Comment: Then how would I know if some unknown exception occurs in the onSuccess that is supposed to crash the app.

Comment: As you would do in plain java, without resorting to rx.. You use a try/catch block. But, checked exceptions in java are for very peculiar cases. Be careful about null values, if you can't avoid using them at all

Comment: I don't want the onSuccess to swallow exception since the exception that was occuring in my app was uknown unlike the example in the question. In that case if the exception doesn't propagate to onError or crash the app, the app's behavior might become unexpected which in not desired.

Comment: What you do in onError is exactly swallowing the exception. You would achieve the same with try{ .. } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
What do you want instead?